# How to allow users to write new content but not update/delete existing content

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

So I have this application where anonymous users are allowed to write but not read a specific path. They are posting data to a moderated message board kind of thing.

But with my current security rules, they are allowed to overwrite existing data as well. How can I disallow updates and allow only new posts.

My current security rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null",
    "inbox" : {
     ".write": true,
    },
    "moderated" : {
      ".read": true,
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `data.exists()` to determine if the object they're trying to write already exists:

```js
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null",
     "inbox" : {
       "$post" : {
          ".write": "!data.exists()",
       }
     },
     "moderated" : {
       ".read": true,
     },
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply, you where close.. So I'll just edit your answer with the correct one.. Your would only work if the inbox was empty, as the "data" with mean the "inbox". So I had to add a "$post" : level and check there to get what I wanted..

Comment: Don't Firebase rules cascade though? I don't think this would actually work since the topmost `".read"` is all that would take effect.